# How can I update my view / scope in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

In the scope, the "ug" property depend on "user" and "age", when I update "user" or "age" why "ug" isn't update? how can I update "ug"

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    user:<input ng-model="user">
    <br>
    age:<input ng-model="age">
    <br>
    user and age : <span style="color: red" ng-bind="user + '-and-' + age"></span>
    <br>
    ug:<span style="color:red;" ng-bind="ug"></span>
    <br>
    addAge:<span style="color:red;" ng-bind="addAge"></span>
</div>
```

**ANGULAR JS CODE**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        var fn = function(user, age) {
            //TODO
            return user + '-fn-' + age;
        }
        $scope.user = 'taven';
        $scope.age = '30';
        $scope.ug = fn($scope.user, $scope.age);
    }]);
```

Comment: thanks,I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `ng-bind="ug"` write `ng-bind="fn(user, age)"`.
Sure, also add: `$scope.fn = fn;` inside controller's code:

**HTML:**

```
ug:<span style="color:red;" ng-bind="fn(user, age)"></span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.user = 'taven';
    $scope.age = '30';
    $scope.fn = function(user, age){
        //TODO
        return user + '-fn-' + age;
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call an ng-click event to update the scope like this.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
            .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
                var fn = function(user, age){
                    //TODO
                    return user + '-fn-' + age;
                }
                $scope.user = 'taven';
                $scope.age = '30';
                $scope.updateScope = function(){
                  $scope.ug = fn($scope.user, $scope.age);
                }
                
            }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    user:<input ng-model="user">
    <br>
    age:<input ng-model="age">
    <br>
    user and age : <span style="color: red" ng-bind="user + '-and-' + age"></span>
    <br>
    ug:<span style="color:red;" ng-bind="ug"></span>
    <br>
    addAge:<span style="color:red;" ng-bind="addAge"></span>
  
    <button ng-click=updateScope()>Update scope</button
</div>
```

Comment: He will need to update `ug` value manually, are you sure, that it is **comfortable**?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Thanks for your feedback, I just shown him an alternate way to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a question, when I change the input once, why the fn will be called twice.

Comment: Where it's calling two times ?